# eslint for redundant double how to changes to valid

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I try to submit the following code

```
if(!!obj){

...

}
```

**redundant double** error , how  can I fix it ?
why I getting it now ...

Comment: Something wrong with  `if(obj)`

Comment: @Keith - sorry not sure that i got it , does if(obj) is exactly the same?

Comment: Related: [Using Double Not-Operator (!!) For Boolean Type Casting](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1784-using-double-not-operator-for-boolean-type-casting.htm)

Comment: A double !, is saying not not,  so if you had true .  !!true would equal true,  !!false would equal false.  So for conditional logic it's not really doing anything.  It is handy for coarsing into a strict bookean type, maybe for print / storage.

Comment: @Keith - so should I use it like this if(obj) ?

Comment: Yes, its why eslint is giving warning.

Comment: @Keith - if so please provide it as answer with the right explanation , that other can learn from ,Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESLint is giving you the warning as the !! is redundant.

An if condition will coerce the condition into a boolean anyway, as an if condition is either true or false.  So what you end up telling the javascript engine to do is,  coerce to a boolean true / false, then not the value, and then not the value again, only to get the original coerced value.

But saying all this a double !, is not always redundant.  For example say your storing data inside an object, and say you want to force a boolean storage, you could !!value it.

Sometimes I even use this just to double check what true / false something returns from the console..  eg.  `!!'' = false`  were as  `!!'0' = true` and `!!0 = false`  etc..